# using unison with bitvise

Tags: ssh, unison

I am trying to use `unison` to sync a Windows machine (via ssh, cygwin) with a Windows Server 2012R2 machine (via sshd, cygwin).

I would like to switch fully over to using Bitvise Client and Server to make use of the obfuscation feature but I am facing problems getting `unison` to accept `sexec.exe` as the ssh executable.

I see an old post https://fogbugz.bitvise.com/default.asp?Tunnelier.2.9937.3 describing the use of a batch file without further details.

My question is, have anyone made `unison` work with `sexec.exe` from Bitvise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, thanks to Denis Bider, developer of Bitvise.

For the `unison` profile, point `sshcmd` to a batch file ssh.cmd. ssh.cmd:

```
@ECHO OFF
[path to sexec.exe] [connection parameters] unison -server
```